# Unable to resolve configuration with compiler Path

Tags: c++, path, configuration, resolve

I have been getting this error message after installing VS code (New computer just reinstalling things) and I ran into this error message after installing splashkit + the c++ extension:

Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath: C:/Users/willi/Documents/Code/102/Test/g++.exe

I would imagine I need to change the path variable but I am not sure.
Thanks

EDIT: I get this error message after using the command:

skm clang++ program.cpp -o One

I'm sure I am missing something easy here, but I haven't ran into this one before.